# forgerock configuration, managed object with same name

Tags: ldap, config, forgerock, opends

I have installed forgerock and an apache-tomcat server with a web app.
This has been set up previously on the server and was working, but something was done so that the previously running forgerock now just serves the config page.
So accessing https://server:port/app serves the config wizard.
Having set up the information required, the config is then applied.
I am getting the following error in the app/var/install.log:

```
AMSetupServlet.processRequest: error org.forgerock.opendj.config.ManagedObjectAlreadyExistsException: The managed object could not be created because there is an existing managed object with the same name
at org.forgerock.opendj.config.client.ldap.LdapManagedObject.addNewManagedObject(LdapManagedObject.java:200)
```

I cannot determine where it is looking to find the previously created managed object with the same name. I have checked all the logs and don't see reference to this object or the name it says already exists. Does anyone know where it might be finding this existing managed object with the same name, so I can clear it and re-configure.

Many thanks.

I was expecting the config to build a fresh instance, but it appears to be finding some existing ldap setup. I have searched the documents and spent a long time on google trying to get a hook into this, but cannot find where this existing managed object with the same name is being found.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you had a working installation of openam, if you lose your config, you need to delete all files where you installed your openam in order to be able to configure it again, namely the hidden directory `.openamcfg`, you'll also need to delete the extracted war file (but keep app.war)